# Django registration redux template rendering promblem

Tags: python, django, django-templates

this is my settings file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.sites',
'registration',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'mytest',]
```

and

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

and this is my urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('mytest.urls')),
]
```

i grab templates from https://github.com/macdhuibh/django-registration-templates repository and added in root directory, so my directory is something like this:

```
mysite
mytest
templates
   base.html
   index.html
   registration
```

when i go to this url http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/ its get this error:

> Error during template rendering Reverse for 'index' with arguments
>   '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [base template](https://github.com/macdhuibh/django-registration-templates/blob/ed6f3fb06bd555d597928d2ff4f358e6f3e9627c/base.html#L13) that you are using has the following link:

```
<a href="{% url 'index' %}">{% trans "Home" %}</a>
```

You can either remove this link, or add a pattern named 'index' to your urls. For example, you could do:

```
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"), name='index'),
```

If you add the above url, remember the import

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
```